# C : Including Header file with .dll file and .lib file on Linux

Tags: c, linux, include, header-files

I have a three files, `Oracle.h`, `Oracle.dll`, `Oracle.lib`.
 These files are in same directory of `main.c` file.
 And I want to include `Oracle.h` file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Oracle.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Oracle.lib")

int main(void)
{
    int crit;
    char P[36] = { 0, };
    char C[36] = { 0, };
    int Clen = 36;

    crit = Oracle(C, Clen);
    printf("%d", crit);
    return 0;
}
```

I used this code for `main.c` file, and compile by `make main` command.
 But compiling this file has error, and I don't know what should I do.

```
$ make problem4_oracle  
cc     problem4_oracle.c   -o problem4_oracle  
/var/tmp/cc9oUwU3.o: In function main':  
problem4_oracle.c:(.text+0x79): undefined reference to Oracle'  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
<builtin>: recipe for target 'problem4_oracle' failed  
make: *** [problem4_oracle] Error 1
```

Please help me.

Comment: trying to link a dll library on linux?

Comment: Yes. Is this the problem of .dll file? I heard that linux use .a file instead of .dll file.

Comment: No .a would be the equivalent of .lib, instead you need a .so (shared object).

Comment: Then, what should I have to do? Do I have to change file extension?Or Just problem of my code?